# How can I set the imageview to take up the width of the screen?

Tags: java, android

I would like an imagview that takes up the width of the screen (or layout) but there seems to be padding around the view that prevents me from doing this.

[image]

With the corresponding xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:weightSum="1">
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:background="@null"
    android:layout_height="106dp" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_weight="0.59" android:layout_width="match_parent"></ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use android:scaleType="fitXY" , for imageView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The padding is come from transparent area on android icon. 
Just remove unused transparent area or use another image.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

to:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Comment: No such luck; didn't seem to have any affect.

Comment: @Sheldon Did you change it in both settings? LinearLayout and imageView?

Comment: fill_parent and match_parent are the same thing

Answer (score 0):

make layout width and height as fill_parent

```
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:background="@null"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ImageView>
```